# Cannot instantiate interface Lcobucci\\JWT\\Parser in laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9

{
"message": "Cannot instantiate interface Lcobucci\JWT\Parser",
"exception": "Error",
"file": "/var/www/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
"line": 95,
"trace": [
{
"file": "/var/www/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
"line": 54,
"function": "validateToken",
"class": "App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 180,
"function": "handle",
"class": "App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 116,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
"line": 726,
"function": "then",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
"line": 703,
"function": "runRouteWithinStack",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
"line": 667,
"function": "runRoute",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
"line": 656,
"function": "dispatchToRoute",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
"line": 167,
"function": "dispatch",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 141,
"function": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
"line": 21,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
"line": 31,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 180,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
"line": 21,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
"line": 40,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 180,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
"line": 27,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 180,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
"line": 86,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 180,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php",
"line": 62,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 180,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php",
"line": 39,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 180,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 116,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
"line": 142,
"function": "then",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
"line": 111,
"function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/var/www/public/index.php",
"line": 52,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel",
"type": "->"
}
]
}

Answer (score 2):

use Lcobucci\JWT\Parser as JwtParser;

$token = app(Parser::class)->parse($token)->claims()->get('jti');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).